# Regex for partial match of word?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to perform the following match?

`^do something$`

.. where matches are possible for a partially typed 'something'.

For example:

```
^do s$
^do so$
^do som$
^do some$
^do somet$
^do someth$
^do somethi$
^do somethin$
^do something$
```

Is it possible to do this with regex without having to string a bunch of logical ORs?

Comment: [`^do s(?:o(?:m(?:e(?:t(?:h(?:i(?:ng?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/jO6hB4/1) - not so nice.

Comment: If a word is partially typed, there could be number of possibilities for trailing characters. Regex works with character patterns.

Comment: isn't that the same as "do  <anything> <boundary>" ?

Comment: There is no number of possibilities as I explicitly define `$` at the end.

Comment: @Zhro: You, yourself mentioned 9 possibilities.

Comment: What's the *real* goal of this?

Comment: @Zhro: Really, just use `^do s\w*$`. Or `^do s[a-z]*$`. Isn't that enough? If you think it is not, please update your question with the *real* data and problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to match partially "something", you could do:

```
\^do\s+((?:something|somethin|somethi|someth|somet|some|som|so|s))\$
```

[Here is the demo.](https://regex101.com/r/oR7dV8/2)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use regex :

```
function isMatch(input)
{
   var key="do something";
   return key.startsWith(input) && input.length <= key.length;
}
```